# How to move items to a different list

Tags: workflow, move

Have two lists on Office 365 SharePoint. One list is the current entries and the second is an archive list.
There is a workflow that stopped working 4 months ago and now I have about 1000 items to move from the "Entry" list to the Archive list. I can manually run a workflow to move each item, but I do not want to manually move 1000 items.

What is the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SP PnP to start the workflow for the items.

Start-PnPWorkflowInstance -Name 'WorkflowName' -ListItem $item

REF: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/start-pnpworkflowinstance?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

I found one way which may be easiest is to link to Access table, then change a field (fortunately I have a couple that are mostly blank) and that forces the workflow to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Download sharegate migration tool demo version and move it from source to destination . It’s very intuitive and easy to use .